# Specify a single char as read-only in C?

Tags: c

Can a single char be made read-only in C ? (I would like to make '\0' read-only to avoid buffer overflows.)

```
char var[5 + 1] = "Hello";

var[5] = '\0'; // specify this char as read-only ?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't make a mixed `const`/non-`const` array or string. The `\0` not being overwritten should be guaranteed by the invariants in your program.

Answer (score 1):

Can't do it, you have to ensure this through proper practice.

Answer (score 1):

strictly speaking, no.
On some systems you could obtain something similar by playng with the linker, e.g. by specifying the address of "var" and forcing it to be 5 bytes before a "read only" section. But it works only on very few cases, and anyway it's not part of the C language.

Answer (score 0):

No, such a concept of a read only memory location does not exist at all in C. C Programmers are left on their own when allocating/accessing/manipulating memory and they are assumed to know what they are doing :D. Such is the responsability that comes out from raw power :D.

If you can switch to C++ then you may consider using std::vector. While buffer overflows are still possible with std::vectors they are less likely when you use methods contained in the class interface. This methods abstracts element access and insertion and so you won't need to explicitly manage memory. Notice though you can still access directly an element that is outside of the vector size if you don't use iterators.

Since overflows are recurring problems in c/c++ there are several tools to help the programmer with these kind of mistakes. Tools range from static language analyzer to runtime detection of unprotected memory access in debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of a `const char * ptr` which keeps track of your `\0`.

Comment: That doesn't help. Even `const char * const ptr` doesn't help. Access to the specific char through the pointer is constrained by the `const`, but access through the original array is unconstrained.